# How can I structure my test so that my rescue clause is tested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, minitest

I'm having some difficulty writing my test to see if my method inside my `rescue` clause is invoked. Here is my code:

```
 def run
    begin
      fail BounceLimitError, 'Reached 5% Bounce Rate' if Reverification::Process.bounce_limit_reached?
    rescue
      Reverification::Process.start_polling_queues
    end
    resend_soft_bounced_notifications
    send_notifications
  end
```

test file:

```
it 'should not invoke notifications sending methods when bounce limit is > 5%' do
  Reverification::Process.stubs(:bounce_limit_reached?).returns(true)
  Reverification::Mailer.expects(:send_notifications).never
  Reverification::Mailer.expects(:resend_soft_bounced_notifications).never

  assert_raise Reverification::Mailer::BounceLimitError do
    Reverification::Process.expects(:start_polling_queues)
    Reverification::Mailer.run
  end
end
```

I looked up the documentation and `assert_raise` is the way to go but this test produces an unsatisfied expectation. Can someone help me figure out how to make this test succeed?

-----EDIT------

I tried the changes recommended with the following code:

```
  def run
    fail BounceLimitError, 'Reached 5% Bounce Rate' if Reverification::Process.bounce_limit_reached?
    resend_soft_bounced_notifications
    send_notifications
  rescue
    Reverification::Process.start_polling_queues
  end

 it 'should not invoke notifications sending methods when bounce limit is > 5%' do
  Reverification::Process.stubs(:bounce_limit_reached?).returns(true)
  Reverification::Mailer.expects(:send_notifications).never
  Reverification::Mailer.expects(:resend_soft_bounced_notifications).never
  Reverification::Process.expects(:start_polling_queues)
  Reverification::Mailer.run
end
```

When I execute the test the error is now that the exception was thrown.

```
1) Error:

run#test_0001_should not invoke notifications sending methods when bounce limit is > 5%:
Reverification::Mailer::BounceLimitError: Reached 5% Bounce Rate
    lib/reverification/mailer.rb:18:in `run'
    test/lib/reverification/mailer_test.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <class:MailerTest>'
```

The test is passing so to speak because an error is thrown but how can I get this to pass?

Comment: Why use `rescue` at all? Why not just `Reverification::Process.start_polling_queues if Reverification::Process.bounce_limit_reached?`

Answer (score 0):

`assert_raise` is not what you want in this instance because your `run` method does not produce that exception. Internally it rescues from it and calls the `Reverification::Process.start_polling_queues` method.

In your test, calling `Reverification::Process.expects(:start_polling_queues)` is enough to cover that code path (along with the `.never` on the other methods).

That is:

1. `Reverification::Process.bounce_limit_reached?` returns true
2. The exception is raised
3. The exception is caught
4. `Reverification::Process.start_polling_queues` is called

PS: @PJSCopeland has a good point, you're method is probably not correct. I think this may be what you were trying to do:

```
def run
  fail BounceLimitError, 'Reached 5% Bounce Rate' if Reverification::Process.bounce_limit_reached?

  resend_soft_bounced_notifications
  send_notifications
rescue BounceLimitError
  Reverification::Process.start_polling_queues
end
```

If that works, I'd recommend this version that does not rely on raising and rescuing from an exception in the same method:

```
def run
  Reverification::Process.start_polling_queues and return if Reverification::Process.bounce_limit_reached?

  resend_soft_bounced_notifications
  send_notifications
end
```

That should pass your updated unit test.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Lucas, can you look at my edit? I changed the code to reflect your suggestion but I still get an error. I also removed the assert_raise like specified but I think I'm getting an error because I've explicitly said so with `fail`. Is this what is happening?

Comment: I suspect your BounceLimitError is not extending `StandardError`. I usually do that (class BounceLimitError < StandardError). But if you don't, it's okay, but you need to name the exception class in the rescue clause.

Comment: UPDATE: a little more reading and it's clear that your application-level exceptions _should_ be extending StandardError. I recommend you fix that up. I'd still name `BounceLimitError` in the rescue clause - it's just a habit.